# How to filter grid data with paging in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am trying to apply filter to a data store which has active paging on it.
I am currently using static data store instead of using proxy.
However, the filter is applied to the current page shown in the data grid instead of the whole data store.

**Case 1:**  I tried to deactivate paging, apply filter and then activate paging again. However, the filter was active for the current page not to the whole data store.

**Case 2:** I tried to add sorter to data store before applying **Case 1**. It didn't work either.

Is there any way to filter all data and display filtering results in paging?

Note: I tried to write a similar code on Sencha Fiddle but grid didn't paged on this fiddle, [there is sample code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11qa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Static store data does not support paging, because paging is done by the proxy and the reader. You can however define the data on the `pagingmemory` proxy (ExtJS 4) or on a `memory` proxy (ExtjS 5/6) with `enablePaging:true`.
2. For `ajax` proxies, paging is done by sending page size and start property to the server. If the server ignores these properties and serves back everything it has in the database, paging won't work for `ajax` proxies. The server may only send back the records that should be visible in the grid.
3. Be aware that an `ajax` proxy also have to deliver a `totalCount` for the paging to work. To see the pagingToolbar working, add to your store: `totalCount:25`. And voilà, your pagingToolbar shows you that there are five pages. Everything else does not yet work correctly, because see 1. Remove `totalCount` again, it won't help you any further.
4. Normally `totalCount` is delivered by the server and provided to the store by the reader: `JsonReader` delivers `totalCount` if the server reports back the totalCount at the position set in the `totalProperty` property.
5. If you use pagination and you want to always see 25 entries with correct sorting and filtering applied, you would have to use `remoteSort:true` and `remoteFilter:true`. In case of an `AjaxProxy`, the filtering and sorting has then to be implemented on the server side.
6. Filters you apply on the client side will always apply after paging, because paging happens on the server side. They cannot be part of the same store on which you set remote filters, so you would have to bind your grid to a ChainedStore that takes your original store as the source. Then apply the client-side filters to the chained store, and the remote filters to the original store.

Comment: You right, I see that, my approach was wrong, also it's just an web application and it should do challenging works on server-side, like that. Thanks.

Comment: When you have `memory` proxy with `pagingEnabled` configuration (in older ExtJS version `pagingmemory` proxy), you can have paged local data and the paging is happening locally. But the problem still persists, pagination is applied before sorting and filtering.

Comment: I found the solution in [Sencha forum thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305119-Grid-Filter-on-Local-Paging). To sort and filter the local data correctly `remoteSort` and `remoteFilter` store configuration has to be set to filter and sort the data by the proxy.

Comment: @MarthyM Thanks for the feedback, I updated my answer